# Two finitely based binary operations whose union is not finitely based, and vice versa

Tags: universal-algebra

Does there exist a set $S$ and two binary operations $+$ and $*$ on that set, such that both the structures $(S;+)$ and $(S;*)$ have a finite basis of identities, but the conjoined structure $(S;+,*)$ does not have a finite basis? Also, what about vice versa? That is, both $(S;+)$ and $(S;*)$ are non-finitely based, but the structure $(S;+,*)$ is finitely based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can answer the first question.

Every finite group $\langle G; \cdot\rangle$ is finitely based (see "Identical relations in finite groups". S. Oates and B. Powell. Journal of Algebra, 1964.) We don't need the unary operation $^{-1}$ or the constant $1$ in the signature since they are encoded by $x\mapsto x^{n-1}$ and $x\mapsto x^n$ where $n=\vert G\vert$.

It seems that every set $G$ with a constant binary operation $c(x,y)=c\in G$ is described by the identity $$c(x,y)\approx c(z,w).$$

However, Roger Bryant found a finite pointed group $\langle G; \cdot, c\rangle$ that is not finitely based (see "Laws of finite pointed groups". R. Bryant. Bulletin of the LMS, 1982.) It doesn't matter if we consider $c$ as a constant or a constant binary operation.

Comment: For the second question: Let $(\{0,1,2\},+)$ be Murskii's groupoid and let $(\{0,1,2\},*)$  be Murskii's groupoid with the roles of $0$ and $2$ switched. The algebra $(\{0,1,2\},+,*)$ has a chain of Jonsson terms of length 5.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I had tried variations of that idea but gave up before I got the right combination. Thanks!